# Updated Android Studio now requires Clang, no longer links to GCC'd libraries

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gcc, clang

I updated Android Studio and now my project won't compile. The project uses Java and C++ (with JNI) and includes some .so libraries. The reason it wouldn't compile at first was because it said GCC is no longer supported. I updated it to Clang, but now it's saying that it can't find functions that exist in the .so libraries (undefined reference errors). From what I've been reading, Clang cannot link to libraries compiled in GCC. I'm not sure I'm in a position to attempt to recompile all the libraries in Clang.

What do I have to install/uninstall to get Android Studio back to supporting GCC? Or is it possible to make Clang work with GCC'd libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [NDK Revision History](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history), the last version that still allowed GCC was r17c (unsupported, but not removed). I downloaded this version from the [NDK Archives](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases), uninstalled the latest NDK using SDK Manager, and unzipped r17c's contents into the "./SDK/ndk-bundle" folder. I am now able to compile my project again, having reverted back to using GCC.